# Visual feedback for Selenium clicks

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, screen-scraping

I'm using Selenium (Python) with the Firefox webdriver to scrape a website. While navigating through the website I'd like to actually see where it clicks. Something like a circle which appears for 0.5 sec after the click.

Answers for other languages (Java) are also welcome. As long as it's Selenium.

Does anyone have experience with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use such function when you are clicking on DOM elements.

```
def change_style(elem, driver, new_style):
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].{} = arguments[1]".format('style'), elem, new_style)
```

And then call this function like this:

```
elem = driver.find_element... #your code to get the element
old_style = elem.get_attribute('style') #save the original style before you change it
highlight_style = "background: yellow; border: 2px solid red;" #change the bg of element to yellow and add a red border to it
change_style(elem, driver, highlight_style)
...
#your code to click the element, and when clicking next item you can change the last item back to its original style
change_style(elem, driver, old_style)
```

So between two clicks, you can see the highlighted web element which was clicked last. Hope it helps.

Comment: You probably want to add a slight pause after the initial style change or the person watching may not even see the change before the page changes.